# how to read comma separated float values using scanf in c

Tags: c

I am creating a small tool that reads csv file data which has got to read longitude,latitude and info from a csv file and write it to another file in java script object notation.
Example:
42.363400, -71.098465, Speed = 21 
42.363327, -71.097588, Speed = 23

Now I know I can read whole line first,then search for , and pick each data,assign it to individual variables.
But I want to know is there any way using scanf to fetch the data to variables at one stretch.I am using scanf like this now:

```
scanf("%f %f %100[^\n]s",&latitude,&longitude,info);
```

Can we tweak in scanf to get this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply place the comma where required: remember also that a single space matches a sequence of 0 or more blanks:

```
while (scanf("%f , %f , Speed = %d",&latitude,&longitude,&speed) == 3)
  /* store in array */
```

Comment: Its working! but I thought I should not put anything other than format string in scanf.Thats why I didnt place comma in there.

Comment: It's worthwhile reading documentation on the `scanf`/`sscanf` family, such as this here: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tpfhelp/current/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.ztpf-ztpfdf.doc_put.cur%2Fgtpc2%2Fcpp_fscanf-scanf-sscanf.html. Put very basically, you can include sequences of characters that must match those in the input stream or buffer. Of particular importance is chac's point that one space can match zero or more spaces in the input buffer. So, having `speed = ` in the format string would match `speed=` or `speed =` or `speed= `. In simple terms, it's tolerant of whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

Further to chac's answer, you possibly also want to be using `sscanf()`, which accepts a pointer to a buffer, rather than `scanf()`:

```
sscanf(csvFileBuff, "%f , %f , ... ",&latitude,&longitude, ... );
```

Comment: Or fscanf if you read from a file ...
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/